# "in which" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, syntax

In the bellow sentence, I think the second "in" is redundant and should be erased. Because the first "in" belongs to "involved" and the second one is an error.

> ... suggest ways **in which** some risks involved **in** such sports can be reduced.

Comment: It's not redundant. The second *in* is a complement of involved.

Comment: If you're looking to remove a redundant "in" then replace "in which" with "by which" or "whereby"..."in which" sounds weird here anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misparsing. *in which* points to a missing complement of *reduced*, not of *involved*: the ways are ways of reducing the risks.

```
 ...ways in which some risks involved in such sports can be reduced.  
          \. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                                                                    \
                  some risks involved in such sports can be reduced in which ways
                                                                     |
                                                               i.e. in the ways named
```

Comment: thank u ! I was looking for the verb and " reduced" was that verb which its preposition is "in" before which